# Google analytics code tracker for sub-domain (tracking two pages)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, cross-domain

I have two pages on the same domain but under two different sub-domain

- french.domain.com/french.html
- english.domain.com/english.html

now THE SAME analytic tracking code is put into both page, and my stats is tracking properly (i think)

**So the question is, it is the GOOD way to do that ?, if that was two complete different pages like :**

- domain1.com/page1.html
- domain2.com/page3.html

will Google track the page correctly, i never try, i do one analytic for each domain usually.
And if one analytic track all different page from different domain properly, why making more than 1 for all the page/domains?

So many questions, not enough answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: For your first example, both sites will track correctly if and only if you use [`_setDomainName`](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setDomainName) to configure the root domain for the cookies. Otherwise, traffic between the 2 domains will create "new" visits every time they move from one domain to another, causing an inflation of visit counts and inaccurate attribution reporting (since your own domains are credited as being external referrers.

For the second case, without mitigation, you'll have the same problem as the first, but the solution is a function called `_link`.

#### Details

Google Analytics, by default, operates under 2 rules for determining the consistency of its data:

1. It has to be able to access the cookies.
2. Once accessed, the cookies must have the correct "domain hash".

Cookie access works under the rules of browser cookies: Depending on the domain you set cookies to, they can be accessed by subdomains. By default, Google Analytics will set those cookies on the current site's domain.

#### Subdomains

In the case of subdomains, you're provided a function that lets you configure which domain the cookies should be set on, `_gaq.push(["_setDomainName","domain.com"]);` This configuration will set the cookies such that they'll be accessible to `foo.domain.com` and `www.domain.com`, as well as just `domain.com`. However, without consistent use of that exact [`_setDomainName`](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setDomainName) across all these sites, you may run into tracking problems. For example, even if Google Analytics has access to the cookies, it will still check the "hash" of the current (or configured) domain against that of the stored cookie. If they don't match, it'll create a new set of cookies, signaling a new visit, with the previous page set as its referrer. (This manifests itself as "self-referral", where you see your own domain as one of its own top referrers.)

#### Cross Domain

For the cross-domain case (domain1.com and domain2.com), things are much harder. Since these are first-party cookies, you're provided no native avenue for sharing cookies across 2 domains. The cookies from the part of the visit will be inaccessible once someone transitions to the second domain, so Google Analytics will create a new visit, attributing its source as the first domain.

This can be OK if the 2 sites are conceptually very separate, and you *want* to track traffic between these 2 sites totally separately (even if you're storing the data in the same profile.)

However, if unified data across those 2 domains is crucial (for example, the first domain has your landing page and the second domain has your checkout page), you have no recourse but to utilize a special Google Analytics function, [`_link`](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._link), in concert with [`_setAllowLinker`](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiDomainDirectory.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setAllowLinker) being set to `true`, which appends the Google Analytics cookies in a query string and instructs the receiving site to set its cookies to those values.

#### Changing `_setDomainName` values

If you're interested in tracking third level subdomains (e.g, `american.english.example.com`), you need to configure the `_setDomainName` with a leading period.  (ie, `.example.com` instead of `example.com`).

The drawback to doing this is that the "hash" resulting from it will no longer match the "default" hash on the root level domain. That is, if up until now, you hadn't been using `setDomainName`, changing it to one with a leading period will result in all of your "past" cookies from being lost, meaning your returning visit metrics will be less reliable.